# Punishment for Own Goal

Tags: rules, football, own-goal

Is there a punishment allocated by the football authorities other than the club if a football player goes absurd and score a deliberate own goal?

Answer (score 6):

Such an event in football is extremely rare, and happens mostly in lower leagues. There is no law punishment for a deliberate own goal, except for cases when it is proved that a player got money from the other team or a group of football gamblers for doing this. Moreover, it is extremely hard to prove that a player scored a deliberate goal, again, except for cases with substantial video or audio evidence.

From the moral point of view, that player will be definitely "punished" by internal club system. Mostly it will depend on circumstances, but that player will have to leave the team, since he/she won't be trusted anymore.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing specific to cover this situation. However, it would almost certainly count both as bringing the game into disrepute, thus meaning the player would be subject to a charge from the appropriate governing body, and gross misconduct, thus meaning the player would be subject to summary dismissal. The latter in particular would be an employment matter rather than a sporting one and hence very dependent on the exact legal jurisdiction.

Answer (score 2):

The point is not whether he scored an own goal or not, but whether he was involved in outlawed activities such as betting. If an investigation ascertains that he scored an own goal because he had some abnormal interest, he'll be punished by the corresponding regulations accordingly. However you can't just punish a player for the sake of scoring an own goal on its own. And nobody would go so obvious as to score a "deliberate" own goal out of nowhere, unless he's mental. Illicit involvements are usually more subtle.

Comment: Actually, there was a player a few years back who threatened to score own goals if the club didn't let him leave.
http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport2/hi/football/teams/c/chelsea/5314292.stm

Comment: @theblitz That looks to me more like a smear-campaign by his former club more than anything. Those allegations are completely unsubstantiated.